# Wild Card Parameter from Oracle to unix Shell script

Tags: shell, unix, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
for file in ${l_file_path}/${l_file_name}
do
    if [ -f $file ] 
    then
            perform some operation;
    else
        echo "No files to process"
    fi          
done
```

`l_file_name` - This variable is drawn from oracle parameter, ex: `oracle.*.txt`. With the code above, it is not reading the files in that directory.

Result:

```
No files to process
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in `ls ${l_file_path}/${l_file_name}`  
do    
    if [ -f $file ] 
    then  
            perform some operation;  
    else  
        echo "No files to process"  
    fi          
done
```

Comment: put ` before ls and after last } in first line .. i tried but due to some formatting i am unable to do this

Comment: You needed to format the code block (with the `{}` button, or manually putting four spaces in front of each line). Can you explain why the backticks are needed and what they do, though?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole .. contents within ` ` are treated as command .. and here it will list all required files for variable "file"

Comment: Yes, *I* know what they do; I meant can you update the answer to explain it to the OP, since it isn't going to be obvious -  better than just in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Answer would be better if it weren't code-only. Explaining what the code does makes it much more valuable.